# Android recyclerview items not displayed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a little problem with my `RecyclerView` object.

Inside my main activity I have a list which I want to display specific objects.
First I create a proper adapter to the list and then I attach it to the `RecyclerView`, as it should.

My problem is for some reason, the list shows nothing. The type of `RecyclerView` I'm using is a custom list which extends from `RecyclerView` class and is intended for displaying an `ImageView` whenever the list is empty. In this case, when the adapter is attached to the list, no empty image is displayed, nor are the list's items

Here is the code for the main activity:

```
package com.silverfix.dgdeditor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.adapters.DocumentsAdapter;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.DocumentPack;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.files.json.JsonPackReader;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.AnimationUtils;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.DividerItemDecoration;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.EmptyViewRecyclerView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.ScaleInAnimator;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private JsonPackReader jsonReader;

    private EmptyViewRecyclerView documentsRv;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private DocumentsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.app_name) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        // Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.nav_item_divider, getTheme());

        for(int i = 1; i < navigationView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            NavigationMenuView itemView = (NavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(i);
            itemView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(drawable));
        }

        ImageView emptyView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        emptyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchCreateActivity();
            }
        });
        AnimationUtils.fadeView(emptyView);

        documentsRv = (EmptyViewRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.documents_rv);

        // Setting linear layout manager for the list
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        documentsRv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        documentsRv.setEmptyView(emptyView);
        documentsRv.setItemAnimator(new ScaleInAnimator());

        documentsRv.getItemAnimator().setAddDuration(Constants.Extras.ITEM_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        documentsRv.getItemAnimator().setRemoveDuration(Constants.Extras.ITEM_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        documentsRv.getItemAnimator().setMoveDuration(Constants.Extras.ITEM_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        documentsRv.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(Constants.Extras.ITEM_ANIMATION_DURATION);

        jsonReader = new JsonPackReader(this);

        List<DocumentPack> packsList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            packsList = jsonReader.fetchPacksFromJsonFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: data not synchronized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            adapter = new DocumentsAdapter(packsList);

            adapter.setMenuInflater(getMenuInflater());
        }

        documentsRv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void launchCreateActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewDocActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        System.out.println("Paused");
        if(toolbar != null)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("Paused");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_action_bar, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_create) {
            launchCreateActivity();
        } else if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the `DocumentsAdapter` class:

```
package com.silverfix.dgdeditor.adapters;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.R;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.DocumentPack;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by David on 08/03/2017.
 */

public class DocumentsAdapter extends ContextAdapter{

    private List<DocumentPack> dataSet;

    public DocumentsAdapter(List<DocumentPack> dataSet) {
        super();
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public DocumentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.document_list_item, parent, false);

        return new DocumentViewHolder(view, menuInflater);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DocumentPack pack = dataSet.get(position);

        DocumentViewHolder documentViewHolder = (DocumentViewHolder) holder;

        documentViewHolder.bindData(pack);

        documentViewHolder.bindClick(onClickListener);
        documentViewHolder.bindLongClick(onLongClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public static class DocumentViewHolder extends AbstractViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

        private TextView documentName, documentDate;

        public DocumentViewHolder(View rootView, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super(rootView);

            rootView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
            this.inflater = inflater;

            documentName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.document_card_name_tv);
            documentDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.document_card_date_tv);

        }

        @Override
        public void bindData(Object object) {
            DocumentPack pack = (DocumentPack) object;

            documentName.setText(pack.getFileName());
            documentDate.setText(pack.getDate());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        }
    }
}
```

Code for the ContextAdapter:

```
package com.silverfix.dgdeditor.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.RecyclerViewClickListener;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.RecyclerViewLongClickListener;
import com.silverfix.javadgd.components.GoodObject;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by David on 09/03/2017.
 */

public abstract class ContextAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    protected int clickedItemPos;

    protected RecyclerViewClickListener onClickListener;
    protected RecyclerViewLongClickListener onLongClickListener;

    protected MenuInflater menuInflater;

    public ContextAdapter() {
        clickedItemPos = -1;
    }
    public void setClickedItemPosition(int clickedItemPos) {
        this.clickedItemPos = clickedItemPos;
    }

    public int getClickedItemPosition() {
        return clickedItemPos;
    }

    public void setMenuInflater(MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        this.menuInflater = menuInflater;
    }

    public void setClickListener(RecyclerViewClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnLongClickListener(RecyclerViewLongClickListener onLongClickListener) {
        this.onLongClickListener = onLongClickListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: `adapter = new DocumentsAdapter(packsList);
 adapter.setMenuInflater(getMenuInflater());
  documentsRv.setAdapter(adapter);` add in `try block`

Comment: make sure `packsList` having value (check size)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I added these lines to the `try block` but it doesn't work. Also I debugged the code and `packsList` contains the correct objects

Comment: write `return view);` instead of `return new DocumentViewHolder(view, menuInflater);`